# MySQL Very Slow for REALLY Simple Operations

Tags: mysql

Something appears to be wrong with my MySQL even with very, very simple operations on almost empty (~100) tables

E.g. `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS hookup_gender` takes 10+ seconds

```
mysql> show processlist;
+----+---------------+---------------------+---------------+---------+------+----------------------+--------------------------------------+
| Id | User          | Host                | db            | Command | Time | State                | Info                                 |
+----+---------------+---------------------+---------------+---------+------+----------------------+--------------------------------------+
|  2 | pegpro_hookup | 130.88.149.86:51593 | pegpro_hookup | Sleep   |   43 |                      | NULL                                 |
| 92 | root          | localhost           | NULL          | Query   |    0 | NULL                 | show processlist                     |
| 93 | pegpro_hookup | localhost           | pegpro_hookup | Query   |    7 | checking permissions | DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `hookup_gender` |
+----+---------------+---------------------+---------------+---------+------+----------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

Whereas a basic table create takes 30+ seconds

```
mysql> show processlist;
+----+---------------+---------------------+---------------+---------+------+----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id | User          | Host                | db            | Command | Time | State          | Info                                                                                                 |
+----+---------------+---------------------+---------------+---------+------+----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  2 | pegpro_hookup | 130.88.149.86:51593 | pegpro_hookup | Sleep   |   24 |                | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 92 | root          | localhost           | NULL          | Query   |    0 | NULL           | show processlist                                                                                     |
| 93 | pegpro_hookup | localhost           | pegpro_hookup | Query   |   25 | creating table | CREATE TABLE `hookup_message`
(
    `id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `related_post_id` INTEGER NO |
+----+---------------+---------------------+---------------+---------+------+----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

What might be causing this slowdown?

What further information can I provide?

Thanks for your time,

---

Info:

```
top - 02:44:33 up  1:15,  2 users,  load average: 1.59, 1.57, 1.05
Tasks:  86 total,   1 running,  85 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   2097152k total,   398904k used,  1698248k free,        0k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,        0k cached
```

Error log

```
root@tent:~$ tail -f /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.err
111107  1:29:00 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
111107  1:29:01  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
111107 01:29:41 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
111107  1:29:41 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
111107  1:29:41  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
111107  1:29:41  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
111107  1:29:55  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 2618946
111107  1:30:06 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
111107  1:30:06 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.1.59-log'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

iostat:

```
root@tent:~$ iostat
Linux 2.6.18-274.3.1.el5.028stab094.3   07/11/11

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.15    0.05    0.08    2.45    0.00   97.28

Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
```

Thanks for your time,

Comment: Why does it matter? Table creation speed isn't a production issue. For one thing it looks like the database shuts down and restarts.

Comment: We need more specfics: 1) Are you using InnoDB or does this happens with MyISAM tables as well? 2) Do you have innodb_file_per_table enabled or disabled?

Comment: I bet you are using ext3 for your filesystem.

Comment: I certainly am, why would this make a difference?

Answer (score 2):

It appears you are using innodb. During a table drop, the innodb engine locks the entire buffer pool and wipes out any references to the tables, and then drops the tables. This takes a fair bit of time when you have a large buffer pool.

One option is to switch to using the Percona builds of mysql. They have a specific feature to help this out

http://www.percona.com/docs/wiki/percona-server:features:misc_system_variables

> When innodb_file_per_table is set to 1, doing a DROP TABLE can take a
> long time on servers with a large buffer pool, even on an empty InnoDB
> table. This is because InnoDB has to scan through the buffer pool to
> purge pages that belong to the corresponding tablespace. Furthermore,
> no other queries can start while that scan is in progress.
>
> When innodb_lazy_drop_table is ON, XtraDB optimizes that process by only marking the pages corresponding to the tablespace being
> deleted. It defers the actual work of evicting those pages until it
> needs to find some free pages in the buffer pool.
>
> When innodb_lazy_drop_table is OFF, the usual behavior for dropping tables is in effect.